# How to hide a div when onclick data-clear-btn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to hide a division when I clicked X on an input text?

```
<input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" id="domainname" value="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
```

---

```
$("#domainname").on("click", ".ui-input-clear", function(e){
            $("#generated").hide();
```

It doesn't work like below.

Comment: I think you are missing one of the elements in your html you are sharing with us?

Comment: could you please share more completed code?

Comment: that click handler is looking for child of an input....which can't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jQM enhances the input it puts it inside a container div with class ui-input-text.  The clear button is inside that container.  So you can add a click handler like this:

```
$("#domainname").parent('.ui-input-text').on("click", ".ui-input-clear", function(e){
        $("#DivToHide").hide();

});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o4ms39vu/)**